# Using of GPIO0 and GPIO1 on Raspberry Pi 4B

Tags: pi-4, pi4-eeprom

I have built customize image using yocto for Rpi 4B.
I want to use GPIO0 and GPIO1 as input/output with /sys/class interface
Can I use them?

I don't need any Rpi HAT or EEPROM.

I have googled so much not clarified answer.

Anyone can clarify ?

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way to come up with a definitive answer is to try.

The only problem I see is that GPIO 0 and 1 may be probed during boot to see if a HAT is present.  Only you can know if that will upset your system.

After boot you should be able to use GPIO 0 and 1 as normal.

You can actually stop the probe of GPIO 0 and 1 by adding the following entry to `/boot/config.txt'

```
force_eeprom_read=0
```

See [config.txt documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/boot.md).

Comment: Thank you @joan
What if I use PoE HAT designed by me which has nothing to do with EEPROM?

Comment: @KeyurThumar That will not make any difference.  If the GPIO are probed they will still be probed regardless of whether a HAT is present ot not.

Comment: The rule from RPF is that these pins should not be used at all unless it's for a HAT.  James has stated this previously on the forum and in the tech docs.  Given the large number of pins available I would not risk it and who knows - you may need a HAT one day.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers.